# Why is my 5D Mark II not firing? Everything else works great

Tags: troubleshooting, canon-5d-mark-ii

I was taking a few pictures with my 5D Mark II and everything was great, then I changed the lens and the camera wouldn't fire anymore. Switching back to the other lens didn't solve the problem. The camera focuses just fine when I press the button. I can even shoot videos with liveview, but the camera refuses to take any photo when I press the button.

I did reset the camera (removing both batteries) without result.

Any hint would be great! It doesn't look like something is physically broken.
Antony

Comment: Have you tried resetting everything? It's on [page 44 of the manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300004270/01/eos5dmkii-im4-en.pdf#page=44).

Comment: Looks like the shutter is physically broken. The shutter is not used when shooting videos.

Comment: I agree on the shutter problem.
You could further test whether the camera shoots tethered from a computer.
Also you can activate the sensor cleaning position of mirror and shutter and have a look whether you see something strange at the shutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning shutter function to a different button and see what happens (5D mk2 allows it IIRC). If it works, your shutter button is broken.

Comment: Thanks. The shutter is broken. I bought a remote shutter and it works great... I need a way to repair that, potentially myself though.

Answer (score -1):

In general: if one lens works and the other doesn't, the problem is with the second lens, not with the camera.

Before you send the camera in for repair,remove the lens that you're using now and try the one that was on the camera before.  If the "original" lens works OK, the other lens's contacts maybe dirty, or the lens may be defective.

To clean the lens contacts, dip a cotton swap in isopropyl alcohol (commonly available in your medicine cabinet or in a drug store), squeeze out any excess so it's not dripping, and lightly scrub the copper contacts on the lens.  You might also scrub the contacts on the camera.  Wait a few minutes for the alcohol to evaporate and try again.

Comment: The poster has already swapped back to the first lens: "reversing to the other lens didn't solve the problem".